# Sangalpam for Dhakshyanam in USA?

Tags: mahabharata

**What is the sangalpam for Dhakyanam in USA for July 15, 2016?**

Comment: do you mean to say sankalpa for Dakshinayana in USa region for 15 july 2016?

Answer (score 2):

http://ranganatha.org has a 2016 calendar pdf.

instead of
jambu-dveepe, bharatha-varshe, bharatha-khande, say:
krouncha-dveepe, ramanaka-varshe, gotheertha-khande

other maasa,nakshatra,tithi,vaar etc. can be seen from calendar.

[Source](http://prapatti.com/slokas/sanskrit/upaakarma.pdf)

Comment: can you provide sankalpam for other countries or mention the source for personal use.

Comment: updated answer with source. that site also has upakarama procedure in other languages