# How to do sankalpa from Singapore?

Tags: sankalpa

The sankalpa we do during devatarchana .. "Shubhashobane muhurte .." seems to be only relevent to India .. Can some one help me to reword the Sankalpa to suit in Singapore.

Comment: Related - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2679/what-facts-can-be-derived-from-the-mahasankalpam-sloka/30050#30050 , https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14089/sangalpam-for-dhakshyanam-in-usa/14097#14097